# Setting attribute value of an element in camelCase using a directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add an attribute to an angularJs element from a directive like this:

```
element.attr('startOffset', val);
```

But when I check the element, the attribute added is 'startoffset' where the 'o' is not a capital letter.

Is there any way to add an attribute to an element and keep the case of the word intact?

Thanks

Comment: You don't. You only set it separated by dash, and get the attribute  with camel case, while using attrs. So just do `element.attr('start-offset', val);`

Comment: Tried that. In that case, it just sets the attribute as 'start-offset'

Comment: Yes that is what i said.. Attribute names are case insensitive, so even if you set it as `startOffset` it will be `startoffset`, and you can get it regardless of its case. Just try setting it without jqlite wrapper, `element[0].setAttribute('startOffset', val);` as see what happens. _Why do you need it in camelcase anyways, what difference does it make?_

Comment: Thanks. That seems to have done the trick. 

I want it to be in camelcase because I'm trying to set the startOffset of an svg text element and for some reason, svg needs it to be in camelcase.

Comment: How did that do the trick?  "startOffset" will still be "startoffset".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set an attribute using jqliteWrapper `.attr` or even with direct DOM operation `.setAttribute` it will lowercase the attribute name, before attaching to the element.

> When called on an HTML element in an HTML document, setAttribute lower-cases its attribute name argument.

Since you are using SVG try direct operation with [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute), however setting attributes preserve their cases with SVG, not sure if jquery does any transformations internally.

```
 element[0].setAttribute('startOffset', val);
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aD25PX?p=preview)**

---

Confirmed that it is jquery inclusion before angular which causes it not to preserve the attribute name casing while setting it via `.attr`, but if you do not include jquery and angular falls back to jqLite it will set the attribute name as is, so that will work (along with `attrs.$set`) with SVG as well apart from the direct DOM operation.

Answer (score 1):

I have created namespace in the main div:

```
<div class="main-wrapper" xmlns="appnamespace">...</div>
```

Then I inserted attribute of html-element (element) in TS code (in JS it is possible too, of course) by setAttributeNS:

```
element.setAttributeNS(
            'appnamespace', 'myAttribute', info.value
)
```

The attribute was appeared in html-template

Answer (score 0):

setAttributeNS adds a new attribute or changes the value of an attribute with the given namespace and name

> element.setAttributeNS(namespace,name,value)

namespace is a string specifying the namespace of the attribute.
name is a string identifying the attribute by its qualified name; that is, a namespace prefix followed by a colon followed by a local name.
value is the desired string value of the new attribute.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me ->

```js
var att = document.createAttribute("newName"); // Create a "newName" attribute
att.value = newName; // Set the value of the newName attribute
parent_tag.setAttributeNode(att);
```