# Is AMP-SCRIPT lowercasing the HTML attributes?

Tags: amp-html

It appears that `<amp-script>` code lowercases all the dynamically added HTML attributes but that seems to break the viewBox attribute for SVG tags.

For example if you have

> document.appendChild(`'<svg height="100" width="100" viewBox="0 0 10 10"> <circle class="smile" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-dashoffset="-.5" stroke-dasharray="11.5,13.6327" /> <circle class="eyes" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-dashoffset="-15.5" stroke-dasharray="0,6.6327,0,17.5" /> </svg>'`);

But the source that gets appended has

```
viewbox="0 0 10 10"
```

Notice that viewbox is lowercased which seems to not work.

Does anyone know if `<amp-script>` lowercases all attributes?

And how to make viewBox work in `<amp-script>`

Here's a reference to an old discussion about viewBox being case sensitive https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1062

The code builds a `svg string` then appends to the document.

```
p.innerHTML = '<svg ...';
                        
document.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: Which JS function are you using that invokes `retval`? IOE only JS functions that (basically) involve a user gesture seem to work. While you can use `fetch` in `amp-script` I've never seen an example that forms an SVG string. Alternatively, you can link an SVG item that is declared in a sprite-like structure (using id=). The sprite needs to be inline (can be after `</body>`); not sure it will work if it's a URL.

Comment: @JayGray Thanks but the retval is simply a string that contains '<svg> ... ' and then it uses document.appendChild.  I'll update the question

Comment: It appears to be an xml vs html issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734628/how-can-i-set-an-attribute-with-case-sensitive-name-in-a-javascript-generated-el/28734954

Comment: My best idea is to invoke the id from this structure: `<svg style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs> <symbol id=""></symbol></defs></svg>`